# Android Bundle = .NET Session[]?

Tags: android, bundle

The description of Android Bundle says:

> Bundles are Android's way of maintaining and passing program state. The system is constructed around the assumption that any program (characterized by a collection of activities) may be preempted at any time, and if the system resources are low, may be subsequently killed. To handle this difficulty, a Bundle called an icicle is saved whenever the activity is preempted.
>
> Like with a hash table or dictionary, items added to the Bundle are given a key which is later used to retrieve the data (using data-type specific methods like getCharacter(String key) and getParcelable(String key)). When you are creating activities, be sure to save any important state information into the icicle given to onFreeze so that you can restore your program in onCreate if it is killed while suspended.

Is Bundle the same as Session[] in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, no.

In .NET the you can access the State object from anywhere at any time, and you will be pretty sure that objects that you have placed inside of it will still be there when you are calling it. The session expires though, and unless you have saved anything in your viewstate, that data becomes lost.

Android uses Bundles because of the nature of the OS, it will keep your application "alive" in the background where state is preserved, but if it deems that your application is idle and that it can be killed, it will kill your app to free up resources. Before your app process is killed it will call `onFreeze()` (now renamed to `onSaveInstanceState()`) which will give you the opportunity to save data to the Bundle that will be passed to onCreate the next time your application starts up (so you can initialize your screen again).

Comment: So Bundle keeps data like dictionary does. Ok. How long does it keep it? Until the app has been killed? Longer - until the system reboot? Permanently?

Comment: The Bundle is passed to your application as a parameter when a Activity is started or resumed. When the application is suspended for whatever reason, you add things to your bundle in onSaveInstanceState method. The bundle will be passed again when it is restarted using onRestoreInstanceState. Once the process is killed and restarted, a new Bundle will be used. In short, the Bundle is only "alive" while your application is actually alive and will be lost when the app is killed. If you need persistent data, use Shared Preferences.